# Cordova (PhoneGap) Corona

Tags: cordova, coronasdk

Hi using corona sdk to build apps. I would like to know whether it is possible to use PhoneGap/Cordova to with Corona. I have an app which requires the user to record video and as Corona do not support this at this stage I was hoping I could use the Cordova API or another alternative that allows me to record video using Corona.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Recently there was a [Corona blog post](http://www.coronalabs.com/blog/2012/10/22/corona-phonegap-physics-android-notifications-and-more/) which demo'ed injecting Phonegap functionality within a Corona app. Based on comments, it not available yet, but coming soon!

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am assuming there are no other alternatives you might be aware of.

Comment: I am afraid not. Recent releases of PhoneGap make it easy to embed them in native application and I guess that is what Corona is planning on using to embed it.